# Computing integral with the Trapezoidal Rule (the approximate value of the integral, and the number of iterations)

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, rule, integral

The program needs to compute define integral with a predetermined
accuracy (eps) with the Trapezoidal Rule and my function needs to return:

1.the approximate value of the integral.

2.the number of iterations.

My code:

```
    from math import *
    def f1(x):
       return (x ** 2 - 1)**(-0.5)

    def f2(x):
       return (cos(x)/(x + 1))

    def integral(f,a,b,eps):
       n = 2
       x = a
       h = (b - a) / n
       sum = 0.5 * (f(a) + f(b))
       for i in range(n):
          sum = sum + f(a + i * h)
       sum_2 = h * sum
       k = 0
       flag = 1

       while flag == 1:
          n = n * 2
          sum = 0
          k = k + 1
          x = a
          h = (b - a) / n
          sum = 0.5 * (f(a) + f(b))
          for i in range(n):
             sum = sum + f(a + i * h)
          sum_new = h * sum
          if eps > abs(sum_new - sum_2):
             t1 = sum_new
             t2 = k
             return t1, t2
          else:
             sum_2 = sum_new

   x1 = float(input("First-begin: "))
   x2 = float(input("First-end: "))
   y1 = float(input("Second-begin: "))
   y2 = float(input("Second-end: "))
   int_1 = integral(f1,x1,y1,1e-6)
   int_2 = integral(f2,x2,y2,1e-6)
   print(int_1)
   print(int_2)
```

It doesn't work correct. Help, please!

Comment: Did you already ask your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)?

Comment: Please be much more specific than "It doesn't work correct." What test case did you try, what output did you expect, and what output or traceback did you get instead?

Comment: In `integral` you repeatedly use `for i in range(n): sum = sum + f(a + i * h)` but the body of such a loop is evaluated, in the case, e.g., of `n=2` for `i-0` and `i=1` so that you have that, at the end of the loop, `sum=f(a)+f(a+h)` and this is not what you want, won't you?

Answer (score 0):

You implemented the math wrong. The error is in the lines

```
for i in range(n):
    sum = sum + f(a + i * h)
```

`range(n)` always starts at 0, so in your first iteration you just add the `f(a)` term again.
If you replace it with

```
for i in range(1, n):
      sum = sum + f(a + i * h)
```

it works.

Also, you have a ton of redundant code; you basically coded the core of the integration algorithm twice. Try to follow the [DRY-principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 0):

The trapezoidal rule of integration simply says that an approximation to the integral $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ is `(b-a) (f(a)+f(b))/2`. The error is proportional to `(b-a)^2`, so that it is possible to have a better estimate using the *composite* rule, i.e., subdividing the initial interval in a number of shorter intervals.

Is it possible to use shorter intervals and still reuse the function values previously computed, so minimizing the total number of function evaluation?

Yes, it is possible if we divide each interval in two equal parts, so that at stage `0` we use 1 intervals, at stage `1` 2 equal intervals and in general, at stage `n`, we use 2<sup>n</sup> equal intervals.

Let's start with a simple problem and see if it possible to generalize the procedure…

```
a, b = 0, 32
L = b-a = 32
```

by the trapezoidal rule the initial approximation say `I0`, is given by

```
I0 = L * (f0+f1)/2
   = L * S0
```

with `S0 = (f0+f1)/2`; a pictorial representation of the real axis, the coordinates of the interval extremes and the evaluated functions follows

```
x0                             x1
01234567890123456789012345679012
f0                             f1
```

Next, we divide the original interval in two,

```
L = L/2

x0              x2             x1
01234567890123456789012345679012
f0              f2             f1
```

and the new approximation, stage `n=1`, is obtained using two times the trapezoidal rule and applying a bit of algebra

```
I1 = L * (f0+f2)/2 + L * (f2+f1)/2
   = L * [(f0+f1)/2 + f2]
   = L * [S0 + S1]
```

with `S1 = f2`

Another subdivision, stage `n=2`, `L = L/2` and

```
x0      x3      x2      x4      x1  
012345678901234567890123456789012
f0      f3      f2      f4      f1

I2 = L * [(f0+f3) + (f3+f2) + (f2+f4) + (f4+f1)] / 2
   = L * [(f0+f1)/2 + f2 + (f3+f4)]
   = L * [S0+S1+S2]
```

with `S2 = f3 + f4`.

It is not difficult, given this picture,

```
x0  x5  x3  x6  x2  x7  x4  x8  x1
012345678901234567890123456789012
f0  f5  f3  f6  f2  f7  f4  f8  f1
```

to understand that our next approximation can be computed as follows

```
L = L/2
S3 = f5+f6+f7+f8
I3 = L*[S0+S1+S2+S3]
```

Now, we have to understand how to compute a generalization of `Sn,
n = 1, …` — for us, the pseudocode is

```
L_n = (b-a)/2**n
list_x_n = list(a + L_n + 2*Ln*j for j=0, …, 2**n-1) 
Sn = Sum(f(xj) for each xj in list_x_n)
```

For `n = 3`, `L = (b-a)/8 = 4`, we have from the formula above `list_x_n = [4, 12, 20, 28]`, please check with the picture...

Now we are ready to code our algorithm in Python

```
def trapaezia(f, a, b, tol):
     "returns integ(f, (a,b)), estimated error and number of evaluations"

     from math import fsum # controls accumulation of rounding errors in sums

     L = b - a
     S = (f(a)+f(b))/2
     I = L*S
     n = 1
     while True:
         L = L/2
         new_points = (a+L+j*L for j in range(0, n+n, 2))
         delta_S = fsum(f(x) for x in new_points)
         new_S = S + delta_S
         new_I = L*new_S
         # error is estimated using Richardson extrapolation (REP)
         err = (new_I - I) * 4/3
         if abs(err) > tol:
             n = n+n
             S, I = new_S, new_I
         else:
             # we return a better estimate using again REP
             return (4*new_I-I)/3, err, n+n+1
```

If you are curious about Richardson extrapolation, I recommend [this document](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m101/richard.pdf) that deals exactly with the application of REP to the trapezoidal rule quadrature algorithm.

If you are curious about `math.fsum`, [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/math.html#math.fsum) don't say too much but [the link](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/393090/) to the original implementation that also includes an extended explanation of all the issues involved.

Comment: Thanks very much!!! But fsum doesn't work: Error: can't convert complex to float. This error happens with float numbers, with another - everything is okey.

Comment: `fsum` works _only_ with real numbers, if your program raises the error that you reported, it's because you have passed to `trapaezia` a function `f` that, at least in some cases, returns complex numbers, implying that `fsum` at some point stumbles upon a complex value...  I think that this issue could be better dealt within the frame of a new question.